# Problem when Client (react) and Server(nodejs) are in the same folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my web application, that has my client and server at the same main folder, to Heroku and I face some annoying problem that the server isn't serving the react build folder.

Here's my project folder tree:

```
/client
/api
app.js
server.js
```

`app.js` => routes, loading models, controllers, etc

`server.js` => server configuration

Here's the content of `server.js`, I believe the problem is here

```
const app = require('./app');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');

app.use(cors())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log('we are on production!')
  app.use(express.static('./client/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('redirecting to react app build')
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on PORT ${port}`))
```

It never gets to the `console.log('redirecting to the react app build')` part

When I entered my heroku server I face the server side instead of my react build. why is that so?

Comment: Could you check if your environment variable `NODE_ENV` exists and is equal to `production` ?

Comment: try stripping your code of all unnecessary code, app.use(express.static('./client/build')); should be the only line you need for this to work, see if that serves the frontend and go from there

Comment: @Hurobaki Yes, Production is True

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh It's working! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Dor does my answer help you ?

Comment: Your answer gave me hope, but I'm still struggling to find a solution to my project :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a test project using your architecture. My project is running and uploaded on Heroku right now. I'm gonna detail all steps I just do to make it works according to given information.

So my project architecture :

```
client/ // from CRA
package.json
server.js
.env
```

Configure your environment variable :

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production // this for production heroku
```

In my `.env` file I set local environment variables such as :

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

Here's my main `package.json` file which I defined a `heroku-postbuild` to create the client build folder.

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "mit",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "path": "0.12.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && yarn && yarn build"
  }
}
```

And the `server.js` file, almost the same as the one provided

```
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log('we are on production!')
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('redirecting to react app build')
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on PORT ${port}`))
```

You can run Heroku in local by typing this command `heroku local` in will loaded the `.env` file with environment variables.

To test production Heroku you have to type `heroku open`. Don't forget to set up "production" environment variable with command I wrote above.

Everything's working fine. I can upload my code to Github if you want me to.

Comment: I'm finally able to deploy successfully but I'm only able to access either the server or the client. Is it possible to run both at the same time, while the two able to speak to each other, or I'm just looking into something that cannot be done?

Comment: everything is working as I want now. It could be the ENV variables that I didn't set up. This is the first time I do anything in Heruko, and working with Nodejs in general. Thank you so much for the guidance. Cheers buddy!